Setting up liquibaseSchemaName for Liquibase with MS-SQL Server
I am using Liquibase with SQL Server (Microsoft SQL Server 2016) and Spring Boot. By default, Liquibase uses the dbo schema for the databasechangelog and databasechangeloglock tables. However, I want to use a different schema for these tables.
Here are my Liquibase properties in the application.properties file:
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

According to the documentation, liquibaseSchemaName properties can be used to set a specific schema name, but it doesn't work in the application.properties file.
Is there a way to specify the schema where Liquibase creates the databasechangelog and databasechangeloglock tables?

Aside... mainstream support for SQL Server 2016 ended three years ago and extended support will end in 2026. You should already be migrating your applications to a newer version.

Have you looked into spring.liquibase.default-schema and spring.liquibase.parameters.schema yet?

yep, We are on migration process. Liquibase integration is already part of migration to SQL Server 2019.
I can't override spring.liquibase.default-schema for sql server, it always chooses dbo schema which is the default schema of connection
also spring.liquibase.parameters.schema parameter is not working.
